# Getting 404 error while jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

Tags: typescript, nuget-package

I was trying to install jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped in my project but I am getting following error:

```
Install-Package : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At line:1 char:16
    + Install-Package <<<<  jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I was giving following command in package-manager Console:

```
Install-Package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
```

above command is copied from : http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

please help..

Comment: Try again : https://twitter.com/nuget/status/371065487502737408

Answer (score 1):

Basarat answer gives you the place where you can get all of the files from, but if you have Nodejs, with `npm` installed, then there is an alternative method. For those who do not have nodejs with `npm`, please download it from [here](http://nodejs.org/). `npm` is short for Node Package Manager.

You can then go to your command line, then then just use `npm`.

You can then install `tsd` which is short of TypeScript Definition Manager like so:

`npm install -g tsd`

Then you can install any typescript definition that is available like so:

`tsd install <package_name>`

All packages will be installed under `d.ts > [package_name] > [definition_file]`

All definition files have a `d.ts` file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it manually from here https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

To be more exact this is the file : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery